# Can we write the audio buffer in to a file that we get as part of Remote IO callbacks?

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudiorecorder, remoteio

Can we write the audio buffer in to a file that we get as part of Remote IO callbacks?

Is recording and storing the recordings to a file restricted to AVAudioRecorder?

***NEED A NEW TAG::*** remote-io

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure but you can try AVAssetWriter and AVAssetWriterInput

Comment: Were you able to write to the file? My file dump results in distorted audio.